# iOS save data and send when network(2g/3g) becomes available

Tags: ios

I am writing a first iOS app.. It's just getting user input and sending it to customized API.
However, when the user is in some black spot (no signal), I want the app to save the data into local and automatically send it when network becomes available..

What is the best and simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reachability to detect whether the user has an Internet connection or not. If they do, send the data normally. If they don't have an Internet connection, then save the data into the Documents Directory or using NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:object forKey:@"Data1"];

NSString *string = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Data1"];
```